# How should I store pug-formatted content in a database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a javascript app and I'm using [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) for templates and [diskdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diskdb) for storing data.

I have some content formatted with pug syntax which could look something in a format like:

```
p some content here
p some more content here
p: #[span this is the start of the para] #[a(href="http://example.com") a link] #[span and this is the rest of the paragraph]
```

How could I approach storing this content in my database? So far I've only had to store plain text, but I may need to store some text with links in or bold words for example.

Comment: I wonder why this post attracted 3 trolls who couldn't be bothered to explain themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have four data points.  Here's one way to store the data:

```
{
  "opening": "this is the start of the para",
  "url": "http://example.com",
  "link": "a link"
  "closing": "and this is the rest of the paragraph"
}
```

This would get sent to the template like this:

```
res.render('templateName', { "paragraph": <results from db> });
```

Which you can then output in pug like this:

```
p
  span= paragraph.opening
  | &nbsp;
  span
    a(href= paragraph.url)= paragraph.link
  | &nbsp;
  span= paragraph.closing
```

(the `|` outputs raw text after it, and `&nbsp;` forces the space character)

Perhaps a better way to store it would be like to insert a token into the paragraph text:

```
{
  "text": "this is the start of the para @link and this is the rest of the paragraph",
  "url": "http://example.com",
  "link": "a link"
}
```

Then you could output it like this in pug:

```
p= paragraph.text.replace(/@link/, '<a href="' + paragraph.url + '">' + paragraph.link + '</a>')
```

Comment: this gives some good food for thought for atttacking the problem. thanks. Any idea what may have caused the downvotes?

Comment: No idea, this can be a fickle community that isn't always kind.